# Push Existing Git to New Branch

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, version, github-for-windows

I've been having some issues trying to get my branch pushed to Git and haven't been able to find a straight forward answer I could follow.

I downloaded a clone'd a repository and did some changes. Then, I created a new branch on Github entitled 'features/library'.

I then completed:

- `git switch features/library`
- `git status`
- `git add *`
- `git commit -am 'My message'`
- `git branch --set-upstream-to origin feature/library`
- `git push origin features/library`

I am given an error of:

```
 ! [rejected]        feature/library -> feature/library (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Looking at the error, no code seems to be behind our main branch although it is throwing an error. We have many changes on this new commit, which may be why the error is being thrown.

**I would be able to like to push my local branch to its new branch on Github without overwriting my existing local files / changes and affecting the main branch.**

I appreciate any help!
Cheers!

Comment: Git pushes *commits*, not files. This means you need to know precisely what a commit is, how Git finds commits, and how Git deals with commits. See [Timothy Truckle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442160/1256452) for a very brief overview: the lowercase letters in it represent commits.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, that the commit you created the branch on GitHub is not a direct predecessor of the commit you started your local branch from:

```
a -- b -- c -- d <- origin/features/library
            \- e -- f <- features/library
```

You have 2 Options:

1. `rebase` your local branch on top of the remote branch

   ```
    git fetch
    git rebase -i origin/features/library
    git push
   ```

   this results in

   ```
   a -- b -- c -- d -- e' -- f' [origin/]features/library
   ```
2. The more dangerous version is to *force push* your local state of the history to the remote repository

   ```
     git fetch
     git push --force-with-lease
   ```

   then you get

   ```
   a -- b -- c -- e -- f [origin/]features/library
   ```

   Notice that the commit `d` has gone!
   (in fact all commits following the *last common anchester* until and including the current remote branches HEAD will be lost).

   When opting for this method I strongly recommend **not** to use the shorter switch <strike>`-f`</strike> since it does not require to fetch first raising the risk to loose commits accidentally.
   **Always be extra careful when pushing with either one force option!**

Having written this the better option would have been to create the remote branch implicitly by just pushing to the remote without creating it on GitHub beforehand.

Comment: Won't I still have to worry about my local changes being overwritten when running fetch, as well as my MAIN/origin branch being overwritten?

Comment: @Mark-exe `fetch` does not overwrite anything. It simply updates your local copy of the repository with the change someone else made. Your local changes are **always** distinct with this remote changes. **BUT** when force-pushing your changes to the remote you can "overwrite" the changes of someone else.